# Moving the cursor with intellij idea vim

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using ideavim in pycharm.
I use ht key when I move the cursor(remap it because it's a dvorak keymap)

Just pressing the ht key (move) does not work.the cursor moves when the ht key is pressed for the second time.

Why does not it move at once?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: Thanks.
grep -w error log/pycharm, I got "at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:145)"

Is this a direct relationship? Or can you do a better search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry!!
I wrote nnoremap tg gT to .ideavimrc.
Remove it. it does work!